# Setting Variable to an Instance on disk without calling AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Let's say I have two classes, both of which inherit from UnityEngine.ScriptableObject:

-CutScene
-AnimationCollection

The CutScene class holds the dialogue tree, camera cuts, has a public AnimationCollection field. The Animation Collection holds the actual animation data for animations used in a given cut scene.

In our pipeline, CutScene instances are generated by an export process, which saves them as unity .asset files.

An animator uses a unity editor tool to put animations into an AnimationCollection, then saves it out as a unity .asset file. Then, using the unity editor, the animator drags the asset file for the AnimationCollection into the AnimationCollection field for the CutScene that uses it.

When the CutScene is changed and exported, the export code will overwrite the existing .asset file for that CutScene with a new one. We do want to retain the reference to the AnimationCollection that the animator set up. Currently this is done with code like this:

```
cutScene.AnimationCollection = AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath(pathToAnimCollection, typeof(AnimationCollection)) as AnimationCollection;
```

The problem is that loading the AnimationCollection can take a long time (12s for some of our bigger cut scenes). If I know the path to the AnimationCollection, can I somehow set the AnimationCollection field of the CutScene without having to actually load the AnimationCollection into memory? The `AssetDatabase.AssetPathToGUID` seems promising, but I'm not sure what I can do with a GUID string?

Answer (score 0):

In C#, when you set a field's value, one of two things will happen.

If it's a reference type (i.e. a class), a reference to it in memory will be stored. This is a small number that points to a unique location in memory where that item is loaded.

If it's a value type (i.e. structs, int, float, etc), the actual value is stored.

In your case, you're setting an animation collection (a reference type) from an asset loaded by Unity. For your system to work you have to have loaded that whole asset into memory first, so that you can reference it. This means you cannot use GUIDs, or file paths without changing your cutscene system.

To make your system work without loading the files in the interim, consider storing the file path to the animation collection in the cutscene, instead of the animation collection itself. Then load that path when the whole cutscene is loaded.